# Best way to use Json object from @requestBody in controller instead of mapping to POJO

Tags: java, json, spring

Usually we map object from @RequestBody into some POJO at controller. In order to map into POJO we should know the fields from the @RequestBody object. So, my question is what could be the best way to use this object inside controller IF YOU DON'T KNOW THE FIELDS INSIDE REQUESTBODY.

Is it like?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Student getStudent(@RequestBody String json) {
      // then parse the json string into object...
}
```

Please share some innovative ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't know the fields, there is nothing much you can do with the JSON. Accepting JSON that you can not use is an odd thing to do. This looks like an XY Problem. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Based on the updated description of the question and if you are already using Jackson then following code will give you a Map of the json string.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
```

**Note:** I have created a new instance of `ObjectMapper`, you can use the ObjectMapper bean if you have already defined one for your application.

Comment: Point is you don't know the fields inside the json. So, you can't map it any POJO as we don't about the structure of the data inside @RequestBody. In this case I want some good solution. Though I appreciate your efforts for the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can create JSONObject. Follow http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Could be the right direction, however the link is dead.

Comment: @KeesdeKooter Java has many libraries : You can refer Java section at : https://www.json.org/json-en.html